# Как подключиться к одному профилю chrome из нескольких потоков с selenium'ом?

Tags: python, многопоточность, selenium, multiprocessing

Сделал отдельную папку для профиля, в котором настроены несколько параметров, вроде загрузки изображений для сайта (сделал "настройки сайта" -> "картинки"="блокировать" для сайта), пути для загрузки файлов и.т.п.

Делаю запуск `Selenium`:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# в этом профиле уже настроены нужные мне настройки, оно все сохраняется и подцепляется
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=D:\selenium_chrome_profile")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Все запускается и работает.
Но стоит мне попробовать это запихнуть в многопоточность/многопроцессорность, как 2+ потоки отваливаются с какой то сложной ошибкой в которой куча строк `(No symbol) [0x0000...]`, и подчеркнутым указанием на ошибку в строке `webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`.

Есть ли возможность все это дело как то оформить без оформления N-штук папок профиля и настраивания настроек в каждом?
(Понятное дело, что оно можно закинуть `shutil.copytree` если не `os.path.exists` для каждого нумерованного профиля из оригинального, но держать много профилей по 500мб каждый это... как то, да...)
Или может быть можно это как то стартануть в соседних вкладках одного окна одного профиля, но с подключением каждого потока к своей вкладке? Или это будет сильная потеря производительности?

Рабочий пример кода (при `how_many = 1` работает, при `> 1` выдает ошибки):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread


def go_visiting():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=D:\selenium_chrome_profile")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    how_many = 3
    threads = []
    
    for _ in range(how_many):
        i = Thread(target=go_visiting)
        i.start()
        threads.append(i)

    for i in threads:
        i.join()

    print("Fin!")
```

PS Пробовал делать то же самое через `multiprocessing Pool`, отвалилось с той же ошибкой. Пока не уверен через что в итоге буду делать, как разберусь с тем как оно работает буду делать тесты.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте Playwright - асинхронный аналог selenium. Пример:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as pl:
        browser = await pl.chromium.launch_persistent_context('user_data', headless=False)
        urls = "https://www.google.com", "http://playwright.dev", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions"
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            p = await browser.new_page()
            tasks.append(p.goto(url))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        all_pages = browser.pages
        for x in all_pages:
            print(await x.title())

        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())

# Google
# Fast and reliable end-to-end testing for modern web apps | Playwright
# Новые вопросы - Stack Overflow на русском
```

[доки Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/)

Comment: Попробую. Если разберусь как в него переписать то что я уже под селениум сделал... 
PS а может он и падать не будет, хмм...

Comment: А то, что у меня открывается вот чисто в вашем примере 4 вкладки: about:blank и три из примера, это нормально? И еще вопрос, маленький: а если у меня, допустим, сайт playwright заглюкает и будет открываться, условно, 20 секунд, весь код примера встрял и будет усиленно ждать пока не загрузится?

Comment: "это нормально?" у меня так же. "усиленно ждать пока не загрузится?" в методе  goto есть параметр timeout по умалчиванию 30 секунд

Comment: Не, асинк это вот вообще не вариант... Асинка я там не шибко вижу, когда оно "асинхронно" ждет, пока все вкладки загрузятся... Пойду курить как сделать несколько отдельных синков в потоках...
PS а потом какая то страница решит грузиться больше 30 секунд и все крашнется, да...